# Unable to access user coordinates in swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

I can get the coordinates, but I cannot use them anywhere else in the code. Here is what I have so far, NOTE: I have left out the code where I am asking for user permissions etc, but that is all working

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var latitude: Double? // 
var longitude: Double?


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    longitude = location.coordinate.longitude // This correctly assigns the longitude
    latitude = location.coordinate.latitude   // This works too
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}


func greatSphericalDistance(lat1: Double, long1: Double, lat2: Double, long2: Double)
{
  // Code to calculate distance between two coordinates
}

// This is the function I want to use my latitude and longitude variables in
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let item: Locations = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! Locations
    // Get references to labels of cell
    cell.eventNameLabel.text = item.title

    // BELOW IS WHERE latitude AND longitude ARE USED
    cell.distanceLabel.text = "\(greatSphericalDistance(long1: longitude!, lat1: latitude!, long2: item.coordinate.longitude, lat2: item.coordinate.latitude))"
```

But of course, if I try to access longitude and latitude outside the above function, it will not work as they will still be nil. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code that uses these coordinates, it sounds like it's an issue about timing of retrieval rather than the storage of data.

Comment: I have added the code. I would have understood your point if I was trying to use them in viewDidLoad(), but I'm not. Do you think it could still be an issue of timing of retrieval?

Comment: You should reload the tableview AFTER you've gotten your coordinates, not before you've retrieved them since there is no guarantee when you'll receive those coordinates to begin with @BazDaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jay said, you need to reload the tableview AFTER you've gotten your coordinates.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    longitude = location.coordinate.longitude // This correctly assigns the longitude
    latitude = location.coordinate.latitude   // This works too
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.tableView.reloadData() // <- Add this line
}
```